# Самое быстрое обращение матриц

Tags: python, c++, алгоритм, матрицы

Всем добрый вечер! Столкнулся с потребностью сверхскростного обращения матриц без использования np.linalg.inv. Помогите, пожалуйста, с реализацией. Весь мой код слишком медленный. Язык неважен - С++ или питон, но питон предпочтительнее.

Comment: а что не так с `np.linalg.inv` ?

Comment: Всё так, но надо реализовать с нуля

Comment: Алгоритм - находите исходники Numpy и пытаетесь в них разобраться. После этого можно реализовать самому с нуля по образу и подобию ;)

Comment: разве исходники нумпая открыты?

Comment: а разве из закрывали??

Comment: А вообще для учебных заданий здесь принято приводить собственные попытки решения ;)

Comment: Это не учебное задание, это жизнь, к сожалению. Все мои попытки решения алгоритмически неверные, поэтому смысла в коде просто нет, только пост захламлять. А про открытые исходники нумпая я никогда не слышал, расскажите поподробнее, пожалуйста

Comment: Понятно, спасибо за помощь.

Comment: На голом питоне быстро не получится. В том же нумпае под капотом крутятся плюсы и фортран. Так что сразу настраивайтесь, что писать придётся на плюсах.

Comment: @Jho Основная часть тут сидит, как и сказали, на C++ https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/linalg/umath_linalg.c.src А все сырцы конечно тут: https://github.com/numpy/numpy

Comment: А что за матрица? Общего вида? С особенностями?

Comment: Квадратная невырожденная

Comment: @CrazyElf, может я не очень внимательно посмотрел, но imho это pure C (без крестов)

Comment: Вы забыли указать размер матрицы, и откуда она у вас взялась, насколько хорошо она обусловлена.
Более того, точно ли вам нужно обратить матрицу, или решить систему?

Comment: @avp Да я C++ вообще пропустил как явление, может и C просто там, не знаю. Я сразу с C на C# перескочил, поэтому не разбираюсь в версиях )